# Cordova and Phonegap together

Tags: cordova

I am using cordova 2.x on Mac osx.

Can I use on the same computer cordova 3.x keeping also version 2.x?

If not, can I use cordova 2.x with phonegap 3.0 on the same pc?

I need to keep cordova 2.x for old stable apps and create new using version 3.x

Thank you all!

Regards,
Vangelis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

And for future reference, Cordova and PhoneGap are essentially the same thing.